# How to have a form button placed outside the form tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a modal with the body section containing input fields as so:

```
<div className="modal" id="myModal3">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        
                        <div className="modal-header d-flex flex-column align-self-center">
                            <h3 className="text-center mt-2">Add New Contact</h3>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div>
                            <form className="mt-2" onSubmit={onSubmitForm2}>
                                <div className="px-5">                       
                                <label htmlFor="contactName">Contact Name</label>
                                <input
                                id="contactName" 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control" 
                                value={scontact_name}
                                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                                /></div> 
                                <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Add new Contact</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to move form button into the modal footer, but the actual form is placed in the body. How do I move the button to the footer area while still having it function?

Comment: You can wire it up with JS, but you'll need to do some additional setup to make sure it is properly navigable and accessible.  Alternatively, have you checked to see what happens if you just make the outer container of the modal a form?  eg. `<form className="modal" id="myModal3"><!--all your other markup--></form>`

Comment: @AlexanderNied I have not tried that, but my first question would be how do I designate which button would submit the form vs. close the modal, etc?

Comment: Giving a `<button>` `type="submit"` is generally how one designates a submit button, no?

Comment: @AlexanderNied your solution worked, I used type="submit" and moved the <form> under the 'modal-content' div. Thanks!